# Why does Unity heavily blur edges of a single cube despite 8x antialisaing

Tags: unity, shaders, antialiasing, multisampling

I was messing around a random project and everything was working perfectly, when all of a sudden jagged edges appeared on all objects. I've been trying to resolve this issue for the past two dails, only to no avail. I have tried changing various settings, when at last I've uninstalled unity and removed all projects. After re-installing it, however, the problem still persists:

[image]

**What I've tried:**

- changing settings in Nvidia Control Panel (for example, settingantialisaing mode to application-controlled)
- changing the Quality settings inside Unity
- removing any normal/texture maps
- changing metallic and smooothness of the material and removing specular highlights
- reinstalling Unity

**These pictures depict current settings/object properties:**

Properties of material added to the cube

[image]

Camera properties:

[image]

Quality settings:

[image]

Graphics settings:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your game view is scaled x3.47. When the game view is scaled, Unity just "stretch" the output of the camera. Set it back to x1

Comment: @Hellium: that looks like a good answer to me. :) I've also had similar effects show up due to desktop scaling on Windows for high-DPI displays.

Comment: @Hellium, thank you very much! This indeed fixed the problem!

Comment: @AnimaVivens I don't think Hellium has any intention to turn his comment into an answer (should have been an answer to begin with), so if you could put an answer as to how you fixed this, it would be appreciated. (P.S. I know it's just right there, in the screenshot, but still, an answer would be nice.)

Answer (score 1):

The jagged edges were present due to the fact that the game view (first image in my post, the panel in the right part of the image) has been scaled to 3.47, instead to 1. **Scaling the game view to 1 resolved the issue**.

Thank you for the answer @Hellium and for the suggestion to answer @John Hamilton